# D3D11 WARNING when resizing the window

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

If I resize the window and close the application I get these errors:

```
D3D11 WARNING: Process is terminating. Using simple reporting. Please call ReportLiveObjects() 
at runtime for standard reporting. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING: Live Producer at 0x011B0794, Refcount: 2. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x011D85C0, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C88848, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x011E8234, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C77BE4, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C6FC94, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C8F844, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C8F9AC, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C8FC78, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C91754, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C78554, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C70854, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C924B4, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C92674, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C92E5C, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C99424, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03CA8C44, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03CA6824, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03CA6B04, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C9B0AC, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03CA8FFC, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C9B8FC, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03CA79D4, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C76C64, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C7744C, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C9A354, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03CB25B4, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x07D032CC, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x07D0390C, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C9A964, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03C9DF44, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x07D540F4, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x07D0B13C, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03CCEDE4, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x03CA34CC, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x07D02F2C, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x07D0B41C, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING: Live                         Object :     36 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
DXGI WARNING: Live Producer at 0x011A5138, Refcount: 4. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING:   Live Object at 0x011B2328, Refcount: 2. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING: Live                         Object :      1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
The program '[10544] DX_Lab9_Lighting.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

This is my resize code:

```
if (pSwapChain)
            {
                pImmediateContex->OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, 0);
                //Release all outstanding buffers
                pBackBufferRTView->Release();

                HRESULT hr = S_OK;
                //if 0, DXGI will use the width of the client area
                hr = pSwapChain->ResizeBuffers(0, 0, 0, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0);

                if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

                //Get buffer and create a render-target-view
                ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBufferTexture;
                //Returns pointer to the back buffer 
                hr = pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&pBackBufferTexture);

                if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

                //Use back buffer texture pointer to create the renedr target view
                hr = pD3DDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBufferTexture, NULL, &pBackBufferRTView);
                
                if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;
                //Clean up
                pBackBufferTexture->Release();
                 
                //Clear the Z buffer
                pImmediateContex->ClearDepthStencilView(pZBuffer, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);


                RECT rc;
                GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
                screenWidth = rc.right - rc.left;
                screenHeight = rc.bottom - rc.top;
                stringstream a;
                a << std::to_string(screenWidth) << " " << std::to_string(screenHeight) << "\n";
                OutputDebugString(a.str().c_str());
                camera->SetProjectionValues(90.0f, static_cast<float>(screenWidth) / static_cast<float>(screenHeight), 0.01f, 1000.0f);

                //Create a Z buffer texture 
                D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC tex2DDesc;
                ZeroMemory(&tex2DDesc, sizeof(tex2DDesc));

                tex2DDesc.Width = screenWidth;
                tex2DDesc.Height = screenHeight;
                tex2DDesc.ArraySize = 1;
                tex2DDesc.MipLevels = 1;
                tex2DDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT; //24 bits of each pixel 
                tex2DDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
                tex2DDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
                tex2DDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

                ID3D11Texture2D* pZBufferTexture;
                hr = pD3DDevice->CreateTexture2D(&tex2DDesc, NULL, &pZBufferTexture);

                if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

                //Create the Z buffer
                D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dsvDesc;
                ZeroMemory(&dsvDesc, sizeof(dsvDesc));

                dsvDesc.Format = tex2DDesc.Format;
                dsvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;

                pD3DDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(pZBufferTexture, &dsvDesc, &pZBuffer);
                pZBufferTexture->Release();

                //Set the render target view 
                pImmediateContex->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &pBackBufferRTView, pZBuffer);
                
                //Set the viewport
                D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
                viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
                viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
                viewport.Width = (FLOAT)screenWidth;
                viewport.Height = (FLOAT)screenHeight;
                viewport.MinDepth = .0f;
                viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

                pImmediateContex->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);
            }
```

I have noticed that the more times i resize the window, the  more warnings I get. I read somewhere that all the Get() methods increase the refCount, meaning something needs to be released, but I don't know what i've missed. Again, this happens only when i resize the window, so the issue is probably on the way I handle it.

Comment: A fixed set of warning such as these when program exits is ... kindof ... expected. But if they increase due to some runtime action, this is not expected. Difficult to say w/o being able to reproduce. Enable the debug layer, and IMHO, you should use smart pointers over COM references (like WRL's ComPtr or ATL's CComPtr, or C++/WinRT) to make sure you miss nothing.

Comment: I will use ComPtr for my final assessment. for now I'm just doing everything in main for learning purposes, and gets hard to spot issues. btw the issue was that I did not release the previous zBuffer when creating the new one during the window resize. should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that this line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
pImmediateContex->OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, 0);
```

It needs to be:

```
ID3D11RenderTargetView* nullViews [] = { nullptr };
pImmediateContex->OMSetRenderTargets(1, nullViews, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it didn't get rid of the warnings. But I solved it by releasing the previous zBuffer just before creating the new one from another texture.